# Rotate 2d graphics images on fixed background

Tags: java, graphics, applet, awt

I am writing Java code to rotate images on a fixed background image, like rotating a needle image on clock background.

There are multiple needle in the watch, one needle for hours and another one for minutes.

How to rotate 2d graphics images on fixed background?

Comment: Using overlays would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Start with a base, static image (ie a clock face), where the parts you need to animate have being cut out.
- On top of this you can render each element you need at the required locations.

Start by having a look at...

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

You'll need some way to update the movement. This can be achieved through the use of a single or multiple `javax.swing.Timer` timers, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details.

The rotation is a little more fun, but can be achieved through the use of an `AffineTransform`

Take a look at...

- [Rotate BufferedImage Inside JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779877/rotate-bufferedimage-inside-jpanel/15780090#15780090)
- [Rotate an image in java by the specified angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884480/rotate-an-image-in-java-by-the-specified-angle/14885645#14885645)
- [Image not at proper place after rotating (graphics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848053/image-not-at-proper-place-after-rotating-graphics/14851183#14851183) (which is close to what you asked)